# child_process.exec nodejs permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

index.js

```
var sys = require('sys'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

child = exec('./folder/anotherfolder/search.js',
    function(error, stdout, stderr) {
       console.log(stdout, stderr); // Always empty
       var result = stdout;
       }
);
```

Исполняю такой код в экспрессе и получаю ошибку:

> /bin/sh: 1: ./folder/anotherfolder/search.js: Permission denied

Файл точно находится там где нужно, права на папку и все вложенные стоят и на чтение и на запись. В чем может быть еще проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оно так не работает `./folder/anotherfolder/search.js` не исполняемый файл. Его запускать надо так же как и текущее ваше приложение. Что-то вроде:

```
exec('nohup nodejs ./folder/anotherfolder/search.js'
```

Хотя такие вещи обычно через `fork` делают:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var process = childProcess.fork(./folder/anotherfolder/search.js);
```

Comment: `nohup` - лишний. А `node` пишется без `js` :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov я запускаю на серваках с js припиской. Алиас такой.

Comment: То что у вас такой алиас стоит не означает что он у всех стоит. Все же стоит в ответах следовать общепринятой практике

Comment: @PavelMayorov это стандартный алиас. Не я его придумал.